# Android Emulator crashing on accessing Webcam on Mac OS

Tags: android, camera, crash, android-emulator, webcam

I am using Android Studio 3.6.3, Mac OS version 10.14.6. Whenever I create an AVD with front-back camera as Webcam0, the emulator crashes as soon as I access the camera functionality. What can I do to fix this issue?